# Auto reply to sms from specific contact

Tags: contacts, sms, automation

I would like to send an automatic reply sms to a specific text. Is there an app or way this could be done? I am using the default Android sms app. I have searched for auto-reply apps but most don't allow selection of a specific contact. Also I would like something simple and don't need things for Whatsapp, Facebook messenger etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

automation app from playstore is exactly what i use for tracking my kids. i send sms with specific text "where are you" and receive auto reply sms with location (to my specific number only)

found this in changelog to my favorite automation app

Due to new Google Play policy restrictions to prevent apps accessing the SMS inbox:

- Removed monitor inbox option for incoming SMS
- Removed SMS Sent trigger
- Removed Delete SMS action

assuming this rules apply to every app in playstore, you need to find older apk (Dec 2018)

https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/arlosoft/macrodroid-device-automation-2/macrodroid-device-automation-2-3-30-3-release

Answer (score 0):

You could try Tasker

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en_GB

It can be a little intimidating at first but there are lots of guides online for automating stuff, including [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/3ixba0/how_to_set_up_an_sms_auto_responder/) for sms auto reply.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. *Especially, the Tasker Profile & Task needed to do this.*