# Is there an app that will allow me to track my phone without data using SMS?

Tags: sms, lost-phone, development

I have an Android phone, but I don't have a data plan. However, I have unlimited SMS and calling. I lost my phone recently (and thankfully, I found it), but it was hard to find, since I couldn't remotely track my phone using Google Find My Phone, since I don't have data. Does there exist an app that will text you back with the location of the phone when you send it a command remotely via SMS, so you could track your phone without using data? For example, if my number was (647) 555-1212, I would send a message to that number such as `!locate myPasswordHere`, and my phone would automatically text back something like, `Your phone is at N 43.123456 W 079.123456`. If not, I will program my own app. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto reply to sms from specific contact](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220515/auto-reply-to-sms-from-specific-contact)